# How to call enum with a value from a another method

Tags: c#, web-services

In `Interfaces.cs` I have:

```
private enum InstructionType
{
    ADD = 1,
    UPDATE = 2,
    DELETE = 3
}
```

What I want to do is call each `TransactionType` individually in `IWorks.svc.cs` that will handle the logic for adding updating and deleting.

How is this done?

Comment: The title of your question and its content dont appear to be related. Its not clear what you want to do, do you just want to do something different for each value of the enum?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, i want to do something different for each value of the enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to enumerate through your enum type you can use this:

```
   foreach (InstructionType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(InstructionType)))
   {   
        if (type.ToString() == "ADD")
           //do sth here
   }
```

Problem is your enum is private, so it's not realy a possibility. The only option you have is to write a public method in  IWorks.svc.cs that will do what you need, f.e:

```
public void foreachType(Action<T> action) { 
//action can be invoked so it should be exacly what you want 
}
```